# react with IE11 is not working, displaying blank screen

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, babel-polyfill, babel-loader

when trying to load application in IE11 it just shows blank screen and errors with syntax error

on this line

`class App extends __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react__["Component"] {`

[image: ie11 error]

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ccp-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-optimize": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng": "0.0.0-rc6",
    "ng-cli": "^0.7.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-icons-kit": "^1.0.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-side-bar": "^0.3.5",
    "react-sidenav": "^2.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.95",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

I have the following imports in my `index.js` file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'core-js/fn/promise';
```

my webpack is set up as

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].css",
    disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
});

module.exports = {
    entry : __dirname + '/app/index.js',
    module: {
         rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            } ,
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                }]
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/docs'
    },
    plugins: [
        HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
        extractSass,
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ]
}
```

Comment: other browsers i get a state error which i am trying to resolve here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48062682/react-warning-cannot-set-state/48136278?noredirect=1#comment83276217_48136278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have updated my `webpack` and `babelrc` to the following and it is working now.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    'es2015', "react",
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry : [__dirname + '/app/index.js'],
    module: {
         rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            } ,
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "style-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                }, {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                }]
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/docs'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and wanted to avoid `npm run eject`, so I included this script in index.html while in development mode:

```
<script src="//cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

It worked for me with `npx create-react-app my-app` version 1 in React v16.6.3

I needed to also test production but 127.0.0.1 didn't work for me either, so I used netlify  with command `netlify deploy` and it worked.